Getting error while upgrading istio from 1.19.0 to 1.20.1 or later version using canary method
I am trying to upgrade istio froexecuting below cmd fm 1.19.0 to 1.20.1 version, so while upgrading istio executing below command to install core components only.
istio-1.20.1/bin/istioctl install --set revision=1-20-1 --set
profile=minimal, here I am not getting any error my; od is coming up, but post that I am trying to upgrade my istio-ingressgateway & istio-ingressgateway-alb my pods are not coming up & when I saw the logs for all the pod of ingressgateway & alb I am getting error telling:
2024-09-17T07:15:07.201826Z     warning envoy config external/envoy/source/extensions/config_subscription/grpc/grpc_subscription_impl.cc:138    gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_80: Didn't find a registered implementation for 'istio_authn' with type URL: 'io.istio.network.authn.Config'
        thread=20
2024-09-17T07:15:08.045680Z     warn    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config received from XDS server, but was rejected: cds updates: 1 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 1 rejected,

I am stuck here not able to proceed further.
Please help me here to fix this issue .
I asked question related to istio upgrade & expecting a solution to fix the issue.
